# Can I run a application on MacOS from a local HTML site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, macos, applescript

Is there a simple way to start programs on mac from html?

I made an html page with a text field and a number of buttons. The intention is that when a code (numbers) is entered, it is copied to the clipboard. Via the buttons (each of which must open an application) the desired app opens and paste the code into the application (search or something ...). I already made this in AppleScript, but the layout is not that nice. That is why I wanted to work with HTML / CSS. Is there a simple way to run programs on mac starting from html/ Javascript?

Comment: Just throw your html file in your favorite browser. If it has linked files (js, css), make sure your files live all together in a directory and html links are correct. Have fun!

Comment: Depending on what you mean under "open application". As I see you want to POST data to a .php file. Is it local file or it is a file that lives on a remote server somewhere in the Web?

Comment: Modern web browsers, (which is what I assume you're using to view your html via), prohibit opening/launching any local resources because of security reasons.

Comment: @RobC yes, I did read about this earlier. I was hoping to find a way around. The HTML file will always run local on my computer. It's not supposed to be uploaded to a sever/ webspace.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but on Macs you can define custom URL schemes that will launch script applications to handle data. See:

- [Launch Scripts from Webpage](https://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/linktrigger/)

Which is an AppleScript-specific discussion of this:

- [How To Create Your Own URL Scheme](https://css-tricks.com/create-url-scheme/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not sure of what you are looking for exactly, however, if it is vanilla JS, you can open the HTML file in the browser, which will also let you use the JavaScript as long as it is imported properly.

To open the HTML file in the browser, you can go to the file in the Finder then right-click and select "Open with Chrome". If you prefer to use a different browser, you can open it with whatever browser you want.